# Tables with labeled lines

Tags: tables

I have a little question concerning the layout of tables. Does LaTeX provide a way to create tables like shown in the picture below?

[image]

I am referring to the two axes of the table that are labeled "K" and "n". Is there a way to have labeled axes in a table (with a little arrow at the end) instead of just having normal vertical and horizontal lines? Can I use the tabular environment or do I have to use something fancier?

Here is how my table would look without labeled axes:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{l|cccc}
              & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
    $k_1 = 3$ & O & - & - & I \\
    $k_2 = 4$ & O & - & - & O \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Btw, does anybody know what those characters in the table in the screen caption above are? I approximated them with "I" and "O" but it doesn't look quite right.

I would be grateful for any help (and excuse my English, it's not my native tongue)!

Answer (score 4):

A common `tabular` environment seems not appropriate for this kind of table. This is an approach with »[PGF/TikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)« that draws a matrix with arrows between nodes where desired.

```
\documentclass[11pt,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
  adieresis={ä},
  germandbls={ß}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,shapes.callouts}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick,
    >=stealth,
    matrix of math nodes/.append style={execute at begin cell=\strut},
    note/.style={
      rounded corners,
      rectangle callout,
      inner sep=6pt,
      fill=#1,
      callout relative pointer={(-0.5,0.5)},
      font=\huge
    }
  ]
    \matrix (table) [
      matrix of math nodes,
      nodes in empty cells,
      nodes={
        anchor=center,
        inner sep=6pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
        minimum size=1.5em,
      }
    ] {
      ~~~~~~~~~ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
      k_1=2     & \bigcirc & - & | & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
                &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\
      k_2=3_1   & \bigcirc & - & \bigcirc & | & - & | & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
                &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\
      k_3=3_2   & \bigcirc & - & \bigcirc &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\
                &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\
      k_4=5     &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\
      ~~~~~~~~~ &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\
    };

    \draw[->] (table-2-1.north west) -- ($(table-2-18.north east)+(1em,0)$) node[right,font=\Large] {$K$};
    \draw[->] (table-1-1.north east) -- ($(table-9-1.south east)+(0,-1ex)$) node[below,font=\Large] {$n$};

    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+3)] in {5,6,...,15}
      \draw[->] (table-2-\i.south) -- (table-4-\j.north);
    \foreach \c  in {8,9,...,18}
      \draw[->,dashed] (table-2-\c.south) -- (table-4-\c.north);
    \foreach \c  in {2,3,4}
      \draw[->,dashed] (table-4-\c.south) -- (table-6-\c.north);

    \node[note=blue!25,above left=1cm] at (table.south east) {Restliche Einträge analog \ldots};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I recommend to take a look at the user guide to get familiar with that package.

Regarding the symbols it's not entirely clear to me. I would interpret "O" as some kind of circle and the "I" as the pipe symbol ("|").

---

[image]

Comment: This is just... amazing! What a great answer! You even recreated the diagonal arrows... Thanks so much for your help! One question... what do I have to do if I want to add more coloumns or rows? I tried it and got an error.

Comment: @Ariadne: That's actually done in the same way as in `tabular`. Here you need to append columns and rows inside the `\matrix`. Note that you need to adapt the two long arrows after that.